# AttributeError: 'Delegate' object has no attribute '_library'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tpu, google-coral

I am using a Coral Dev Board and I'm facing an error I can't get rid of. I am trying to run on the edgetpu the image classifier example of the official [tutorial](https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board/get-started/) to get started with the Dev Board. I followed the tutorial step by step however when I run

```
python3 classify_image.py \
--model models/mobilenet_v2_1.0_224_inat_bird_quant_edgetpu.tflite \
--labels models/inat_bird_labels.txt \
--input images/parrot.jpg
```

I get the following error

```
  File "classify_image.py", line 118, in <module>
    main()
  File "classify_image.py", line 95, in main
    interpreter = make_interpreter(args.model)
  File "classify_image.py", line 69, in make_interpreter
    {'device': device[0]} if device else {})
  File "/home/mendel/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tflite_runtime/interpreter.py", line 165, in load_delegate
    delegate = Delegate(library, options)
  File "/home/mendel/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tflite_runtime/interpreter.py", line 89, in __init__
    self._library = ctypes.pydll.LoadLibrary(library)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ctypes/__init__.py", line 425, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ctypes/__init__.py", line 347, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc++abi.so.1: undefined symbol: _Unwind_GetRegionStart
Exception ignored in: <bound method Delegate.__del__ of <tflite_runtime.interpreter.Delegate object at 0xffff76ecff98>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mendel/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tflite_runtime/interpreter.py", line 124, in __del__
    if self._library is not None:
AttributeError: 'Delegate' object has no attribute '_library'
```

It looks like the way to tell the interpreter to delegate operations on the TPU is incorrect.
I saw many people facing the same error but none of them has found a solution.
Do you have any ideas ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the output of: "uname -a" and "cat /etc/os-release"
This issue should not be happening on the dev board.

Comment: @NamVu The first command returns ```Linux green-calf 4.9.51-imx #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue May 14 20:34:37 UTC 2019 aarch64 GNU/Linux``` and the second one returns ```PRETTY_NAME="Mendel GNU/Linux 3 (Chef)" NAME="Mendel GNU/Linux" VERSION_ID="3" VERSION="3 (chef)" ID=mendel ID_LIKE=debian HOME_URL="https://coral.withgoogle.com/" SUPPORT_URL="https://coral.withgoogle.com/" ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

base on your answer from above, you are running on an older version of MendelOS. The newer kernel should be `4.14.98-imx` instead of `4.9.51-imx`. Also, cat /etc/os-release:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Mendel GNU/Linux 4 (Day)"
NAME="Mendel GNU/Linux"
ID=mendel
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://coral.withgoogle.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://coral.withgoogle.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://coral.withgoogle.com/"
VERSION_CODENAME="day"
```

Please re-flash the board with the new system image as instructed here:

https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board/reflash/#flash-a-new-system-image

Comment: Indeed, it was a problem related to my kernel version. Thank you very much for your answer !